# Help on preg_match pattern

Tags: php, regex, web-crawler, preg-match

I want to parse a html content that have something like this:

```
<div id="sometext">Lorem<br> <b>Ipsun</b></div><span>content</span><div id="block">lorem2</div>
```

I need to catch just the "`Lorem<br> <b>Ipsun</b>`" inside the first div. How can I achieve this?

> Ps: the html inside the first div have
>   multiple lines, its an article.

Thanks

Comment: why aren't you using HTML parser?

Comment: Because this isn't parsing HTML.

Comment: @kemp, this very much parsing HTML, and not to be done with regular expressions.

Comment: I just see a string matching. People on Stackoverflow get immediately blinded as soon as they see a regex question involving angle brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `id` is known:

```
preg_match('#<div id="sometext">(.*?)</div>#s', $text, $match);
```

Comment: Would not work if the `div` has more attributes than only `id`.

Comment: It will also not work if div changes to `<p>`, so? I stick to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to [use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is not a very nice experience as HTML isn't a regular language. An alternative would be to use a HTML parser like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) library/

Simple HTML DOM Example:

```
$html = str_get_html('<div id="sometext">Lorem<br> <b>Ipsun</b></div><span>content</span><div id="block">lorem2</div>');
echo $html->find('div[id=sometext]', 0)->innertext;
```

Comment: @Yacoby, thanks for recommending this library. I think it's great and it solves the OP's issue with the snap of a finger :)